# bitshift large strings for encoding QR Codes

Tags: string, bit-manipulation, qr-code

As an example, suppose a QR Code data stream contains 55 data words (each one byte in length) and 15 error correction words (again one byte).  The data stream begins with a 12 bit header and ends with four 0 bits.  So, 12 + 4 bits of header/footer and 15 bytes of error correction, leaves me 53 bytes to hold 53 alphanumeric characters. The 53 bytes of data and 15 bytes of ec are supplied in a string of length 68 (str68).  The problem seems simple enough - concatenate 2 bytes of (right-shifted) header data with str68 and then left shift the entire 70 bytes by 4 bits.

This is the first time in many years of programming that I have ever needed to do something like this, I am a c and bit shifting noob, so please be gentle...  I have done a little investigation and so far have not been able to figure out how to bitshift 70 bytes of data; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Larger QR codes can hold 2000 bytes of data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at this 4 bits at a time.

The first 4 bits you need to worry about are the lower bits of the first byte. Fortunately this is an easy case because they need to end up in the upper bits of the first byte.

The next 4 bits you need to worry about are the upper bits of the second byte. These need to end up as the lower bits of the first byte.

The next 4 bits you need to worry about are the lower bits of the second byte. But fortunately you already know how to do this because you already did it for the first byte.

You continue in this vein until you have dealt with the lower bytes of the 70th byte.

Comment: ok, that makes sense...  but what data type should I use that is only one byte in length and will allow me to bitshift?  Also how do I get the upper bits of one byte into the lower bits of the preceding byte?

Comment: You didn't specify the language. In C I would use unsigned char.

Comment: Once you already have the bits in the right place, you can just bitwise or them together (`|` operator in C).